# A function says it takes -const QString &program- as an argument, what should I put?

Tags: qml

I am writing a plugin for a program named Musescore in qml, and I want it to run another program.

Their in-built function for this is documented in the following link:
https://musescore.github.io/MuseScore_PluginAPI_Docs/plugins/html/class_ms_1_1_plugin_a_p_i_1_1_ms_process.html

But for the start function, it says that it takes -const QString &program- as argument. What should I write exactly ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The content of the string or the fact it's declared as const (Which is nothing to be afraid of in this case, just means they will not change the string you throw in there)?

Comment: The problem I was having was with the syntax, and how to write the directory. I tried to just write it directly but it didn't work, but I found out now that I had to write the type of file at the before writing the directory, and also to use two pairs of quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was with the syntax, and how to write the directory. I tried to just write it directly but it didn't work, but I found out now that I had to write the type of file at the before writing the directory, and also to use two pairs of quote marks.